# Is there an appropriate translation for "learning by doing"?

Tags: translation, single-word-request

The term "learning by doing" is also widely used in Germany.

The translation:

> Lernen durch Handeln

seems not to be appropriate in most cases.

#### Examples

> Einen Englischlehrer übrigens hat sich Oettinger, anders als angekündigt, nicht genommen: „,Learning by doing‘ ist die beste Form“, sagt er. ([FAZ](http://www.faz.net/artikel/C31838/herzblatt-geschichten-ein-stueck-weit-schicksal-30328934.html))
>
> Die generelle Devise der Hochschule allerdings lautet *Learning by doing*. ([Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/studium/uni-leben/2010-10/petroleum-engineering-clausthal))
>
> Ausbildung: betriebsintern meistens durch "Learning by doing", jedoch ist keine Ausbildung vorgeschrieben. ([Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/karriere/beruf/2011-04/beruf-erbenermittler))

Are there any better translations, or would this be a case where the English expression should be preferred?

Comment: Now I can go to http://english.stackexchange.com/questionshttp://english.stackexchange.com/questions and ask `learning by doing` vs `training on the job`. Does `learning by doing` in English too me, without any guidance by some teacher? The risk for native German speaker like me, is always that we miss some finer points and be trapped by false friends.

Comment: @bernd_k: While I agree with you on the possibility of missing some finer points, I think *learning by doing* can apply to both self-education and learning with guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eine exakte Übersetzung gibt es wohl nicht (außer *Lernen durch Handeln*, was aber kein so feststehender Begriff wie *learning by doing* ist), und es kommt daher auf den Kontext an, was man eigentlich genau sagen möchte.

Einige Möglichkeiten, die je nach Situation passen könnten:

- Er hat sich etwas *selbst beigebracht*.
- Er hat es *durch Praxis / durch praktische Erfahrung / durch praktische Arbeit / durch Ausprobieren* gelernt.
- Man *lernt ständig dazu.*
- *Das kam wie von selbst.* / *Das lernt sich wie von selbst.*
- *Das kommt automatisch*. / *Das kommt mit der Erfahrung.*

Außerdem liest man gelegentlich auch Ausdrücke, die teilweise auch formeller sind, wie:

- Handlungsorientiertes Lernen
- Autodidaktik
- Erfahrungslernen
- Direkteinstieg (im Gegensatz zum vorherigen theoretischen Lernen)

Schließlich kann man natürlich auch den englischen Ausdruck verwenden, der weitgehend akzeptiert ist, aber andererseits auch zu sehr unglücklichen oder konstruiert wirkenden Formulierungen führen kann.

> There isn't an exact translation other than *Lernen durch Handeln* (which isn't a set expression though), and it depends on context what you're actually trying to say. I list some possibilities that depend on context; the second list contains expressions you'll also encounter, though they're somewhat more formal. You can use the English expression anyway - it's accepted and well-known, and in some cases, it may actually fit into the German sentence.

Comment: "konstruiert" aber durchaus gebräuchlich wirkt bespielsweise "ich habe das 'by doing' gelernt"

Comment: @Takkat: Ja, aber warum dann nicht *Ich habe das beim Ausprobieren/Machen gelernt* oder *Das kam/lernt sich (wie) von selbst*? ;)

Comment: *Das kam wie von selbst* ist ein wunderschöner Ersatz!

Comment: @Takkat: Dann füge ich es am besten der Liste hinzu. Mir fiel da sogar noch eine Variante ein. Wenn man nicht so eng am Original bleiben will, sondern nur die Bedeutung im Kontext erhalten möchte, gibt's ja so viele Möglichkeiten...

Comment: 'Probieren geht über Studieren' am ehesten, aber so richtig passt das alles nicht. 'jemanden ins kalte Wasser stoßen' (damit er schwimmen lernt) fällt mir noch ein, läßt sich aber oft schlecht in einen Satz einbauen - insbesondere bringt es eine weitere Partei ins Spiel, die, die stößt.

Answer (score 1):

- handelnd lernen
- Lernen durch Erleben

But I think it is a case where the original English expression is so accurate and well known that it I would really consider using it.

Comment: While you're right with the English expression being so well known, it also leads to awkward sentences like: "Es handelt sich zwangsläufig um einen Prozess des Learning-by-Doing." or "Ich bin im Learning-by-doing-Verfahren Chirurg geworden". It might be easier to use the English expression in a lot of cases though. I still give +1 for mentioning that you don't *have to* translate.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly corresponding, just an illustration of learning by doing philosophy in practice:

> Meine Einarbeitung bestand aus einem Satz. Der lautete: *Sie schaffen
> das schon!*

As a manager you always have to make efforts in order to communicate negative elements of the company's culture (lack of initial training) in a positive way. So you might say

> Es heißt ja, *der Mensch wächst mit seinen Aufgaben.* Also wir hätten da was für Sie, Müller...

Seriously I think the best translation for 'learning by doing' in German would be *learning by doing*, ditto for 'do it yourself'. In some situations it corresponds to phrases like

> ohne weitere Einarbeitung, *or*
>
> (nicht lange fragen,) einfach machen! (coll.), *or*
>
> mach einfach! / mach mal! (coll., slangly)

In euphemistic buiseness talk or in job interviews people often call

> eine neue Herausforderung

what in more informal situations they may most commonly describe as

> ich wurde einfach ins kalte Wasser geworfen / geschmissen.

Answer (score -1):

I'm working in IT. Here it is very natural

`sich die benötigten Kenntnisse im Selbststudium anzueignen`.

That is because many trainings have the focus to lead to some kind of certification. 
Those trainings are cheap for the employers, because subsidized by the `Arbeitsamt`.

The pain to go through such `certification` is doubtful. If you are already in employment you gain little and risk to have to repeat the examination. (No fun at all)

The things you learn are of moderate value for your practical work. On the other side these certifications might help to get a first employment or after inoccupation.

The other way to contract some external professional is usually very expensive.

`Mittelständische Betriebe` will try to go with the cheap solution.

BTW in 1995 I was certified MCSE (which means Microsoft Certified System Engineer and not  Minesweeper Consultant and Solitaire Expert). I renewed the status for some years.

IT certifications are always limited for some years because software changes often. I hope the examinations some you have to pass in linguistic context are of more durable value.

I started to learn some foreign languages e.g. Italian in advanced age, because I got a bit tired of repeatedly learning for IT certifications of this kind.

And I did it

`obwohl ich in der Schule im naturwissenschaftlichen Zweig einen denkbar schlechten Fremdsprachenunterricht hatte`

Comment: 'Selbststudium' kann aber auch abends, nach der Arbeit, per Buch gelernt, bedeuten.